# MASS Add more Clusters?

Tags: server, maas, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have my local Landscape server set up, and I can reach it on the network.

I hit the openstack (beta) tab at the top, and I have completed 2 of the steps there, I need help completing the other two. Does anyone know how to add 2 clusters in my MAAS server, I have already made one cluster in my MAAS server.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the MAAS docs on how to [register a cluster](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/development/cluster-registration.html).  However, this should not be required for the autopilot.  The autopilot can work on just a single region/cluster master (one machine).  There is no need for the federated capabilities of MAAS to be put into use.

Comment: Yes but when i do that it dosent work could you post all the commands and i also want landscape for this.

Comment: Sure, Probably amend your question with the steps that are failing.

Comment: Ok, also i have landscape here: https://deploy.bloxdata.com